# Is there a way to securely send information in Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, jquery, https

I'm currently developing an application in HTML+JS based almost entirely in ajax connections (using the `jQuery.ajax()` call to ease the process).

I was thinking about the best practice to make secure calls without using HTTPS (at least at this time. I can't afford paying for a certificate right now).

At this point, the only thing that concerns me is the registration and login steps. Maybe the login is a bit easier. I thought of **sending the username and a timestamp, and then encrypt them using the user's password.** So, by doing this, I wouldn't be sending any password (keeping as a secret like in OAuth). The server should check the user, decrypt using the password and pairing the recieved timestamp with the decrypted result. The server should keep the *nonce*-like number into a database (to avoid repetition attacks) and then give back to the user another unique id (encrypted with the user's password). At that point the user should start using that key to encrypt all his information (and probably another nonce) and send it to the server. Please correct me if you find any mistake or leak.

The very big problem to me is the registration. I can't encrypt with a regular password the information, because if I do that in the javascript, any could know the password. If I serve temporary generated passwords to encrypt and I send it from the server to the client, any sniffer could get it and use to decrypt the info.

I know HTTPS could save my life at this point (and maybe that's the only solution), but at this point I'm not able to use it.

Is there any other solution, or should I wait until I can use HTTPS? Bear in mind that if I could skip the wait, it would be better. Thanks mates!

Comment: Note that for internal use or with a limited set of users a self-signed certificate might be sufficient. Either just click-through the error page or distribute the certificate and ask your users to import it.

Comment: http://www.register.com/product/security-sslcertificates/essential.rcmx ~~ $24/year depending on the term. Can't afford? I could imagine the time you waste costs more, unless you are on a shared host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: You can't do it without HTTPS

Longer answer: If you try to do it without HTTPS, you will find yourself trying to reproduce everything that HTTPS was designed to do. You could reach at some point, but it is unrealistic to believe that you will succeed in implementing even the 1% that HTTPS offers. The only benefit you will have would be an obscure security mechanism (security through obscurity), which may be OK for not critical systems, but would fail miserably in a real critical situation.

You could create your own certificate you know and then work with Ajax the same way as with regular HTTP calls. The only drawback is that the users will get a warning message.

Comment: I see... There's just a point I might misunderstood. Do you mean using HTTPS I could skip the encryption system or do you mean I should keep using the same procedures (encryption, decryption, nonces, etc.)? Anyway, thanks!

Comment: If you use HTTPS, the browser will handle everything for you, including encryption and decryption. Security isn't just encrypting data. HTTPS (SSL) define a complex protocol, which guarantees that encryption mechanisms will be applied properly.

Answer (score 3):

Using an SSL Certificate is the only way really, if you encrypt it in javascript anyone can read the code and decrypt it.

http://www.startssl.com/

Comment: That's not entirely accurate: you could implement all kinds of encryption in JavaScript. The certificate is necessary to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: yes, the point in encrypting was not sending the key and using only user-related passwords, not a generic one (to avoid the problem you told). By the way, that webpage offers free certificates, however, how much trustable are them? Well, they're probable a good starter, aren't they? Thanks!

Comment: However, any encryption carried out in a non-HTTPS page should not be trusted, as the javascript itself could have been MITM'd

Answer (score 3):

- Generate a public/private key pair on the server, along with a randomly-generated salt.
- Attach the key pair and salt to the user session object.
- Send the public key and the salt to the client-side code.
- Use the public key and salt to encrypt the AJAX requests.

This would not be a trivial task. You'll probably find that it's cheaper and more effective to just buy a certificate.

**EDIT:** This also means that all the regular HTTP traffic (HTML, images, CSS, etc) is sent in the clear. That could be a problem, since it might allow an eavesdropper to indirectly figure out what the user is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at :

http://assl.sullof.com/assl/

Here is the description of the project :

> aSSL is a library distributed under MIT License thats implements a technology similar to SSL without HTTPS.
>
> aSSL enables the client to negotiate a secret random 128-bit key with the server using the RSA algorithm. Once the connection has been established, the data will be sent and received using AES algorithm.
>
> aSSL is composed of some Javascript files and a server side component. Because I have recently changed the negotiation algoritm from RC4 to RSA, only a pure Javascript (ASP) server component is currently available. I will do a porting for the main web languages (PHP, Java, Perl, Python, TKL, etc.) as soon as possible once the library has passed the beta phase.